# Convert timezone specific datetime string to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

How can I convert `Tue, 01 Nov 2016 02:00 PM EET` datetime string to `DateTime` in C#? What is a good practice to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? There are 100s of examples of parsing dates on this site and others, where are you stuck?

Comment: One of the reasons I love JavaScript is that it's as easy as doing `new Date("Tue, 01 Nov 2016 02:00 PM GMT+2")`

Comment: Where on SO you found such suggestion? ParseExact is way more common suggestion for parsing values coming from JavaScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By replacing timezone abbreviation with zone offset you can convert using `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
string date = "Tue, 01 Nov 2016 02:00 PM EET";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date.Replace("EET", "+2"), "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and if you want more safer way by checking exception then you can using   [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: Consider using `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead. Unless you want to handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) with a format string that represents a generic datetime.

If you can have multiple formats then use the [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes an array of formats.

You can find all the format strings here:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example, "Tue" is represented by "ddd", "Nov" by "MMM" etc.

NOTE: The string formats are case sensitive so while "M" represents the month number, "m" represents the minute number. Getting them mixed up will cause the parse to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) where the format string is built using this [table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Custom date and time formats does not recognize timezone abbrevations. You need to escape them as a string literal delimiter.

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue, 01 Nov 2016 02:00 PM EET", 
                             "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt 'EET'", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.Dump();
```